# Prepending digits to section numbers in ToC

Tags: conditionals, titletoc

I have more than ten sections that I want to list in the ToC as the following:

[image]

Which means I need to prepend `0`s to sections of `\ifnum\thesection<10`.
How do I do this in the ToC?

`MWE` :

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{
    \ifnum\thesection<10 Q 0\thesection
    \else Q \thesection \fi
}{0.5em}{}
\titlecontents{section}[0.5em]{}{
    \large \textbf{Q\contentsmargin{20pt} \thecontentslabel\enspace} }
    {\contentsmargin{20pt}\normalfont}{\titlerule*[1mm]{ $\cdot$}\contentspage}
    [\addvspace{-2pt}]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{}
    % Returns "Q  1 ..." for ToC
    % Returns "Q 01 ..." for Section Heading

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick and dirty: Edit the ToC-file.

Answer (score 1):

This is my try by redefining `\thesection`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\ifnum\value{section}<10 Q~{0\arabic{section}}\else Q~\arabic{section}\fi}
%\makeatother
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}

\end{document}
```

[image]